# New York state income taxes for out of state remote worker

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, new-york, utah

I am looking at taking a job offer from a company based in New York. The position is fully remote and I live in Utah.

I have been trying to find information on what my state income taxes will look like if I take the job. What I find online is very confusing. I was hoping for some clear-cut information on what taxes I would be paying.

Specifically, **would I pay any New York state income tax?** I assume I would pay Utah state income tax no matter what since I am a Utah resident.

Bonus: If I do pay New York taxes, what rates would I be paying?